# What to call a person who always says he can do everything?

Tags: word-choice

What to call a person who always says (as an example): I'm the strongest one. Says that he can do and do and whatever (But actually just boasting, whether he can or can't, but mostly ineffective)...

Comment: Actually, The Strongest is pretty fitting for this. Ice Fairy, ⑨, Baka or just plain [Cirno](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/cirno) work too ... I'm sorry but it *had* to be said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bragger**

(braggart also)

> (someone who) say(s) something in a boastful manner

The definition of bragger leads to:

**Boast(er)**, which also works...

> talk with excessive pride and
>   self-satisfaction about one's achievements, possessions, or *abilities*:

The dictionary indicates that 'boast' as a noun doesn't include the definition of a a person who boasts - as in 'stop being such a boast' - but I'd be happy saying that in conversation myself ... Guess I've been wrong all this time :)

(Both from the Oxford Dictionary of English, via Apple Dictionary App)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[megalomaniac](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/megalomania)*

> Delusion about one’s own power or importance (typically as a symptom of manic or paranoid disorder).

Similarly, *[delusions of grandeur](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/delusions-of-grandeur)*

> A false impression of one’s own importance.

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: I think you got it wrong, I edited the question you may get it correctly, I'm a bit bad at English. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

He is *overconfident*.

> Overconfident- having or showing assurance and self-reliance in an
>   excessive degree

Answer (score 0):

**topper**

From Dilbert, constant one upmanship, and just has to go one more!

http://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=Topper